# Jquery validation remove rules not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am setting validation dynamically based on input. Before adding validation I am removing rule and adding it element is required. Message is not going away after I set rules remove.

```
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        switch (data[i]["FieldName"]) {
            case "ADDRESS_1":             
                $('[name="HomeAddress1Text"]').rules("remove");               
                if (data[i]["Required"] == true) {
                    $('[name="HomeAddress1Label"]').addClass("required");
                    $('[name="HomeAddress1Text"]').rules("add", {
                        required: true,
                        messages: {
                            required: "Required"
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $('[name="HomeAddress1Label"]').removeClass("required");
                }
                break;
 case "ADDRESS_2":
                 $('[name="HomeAddress2Text"]').rules("remove");              
                if (data[i]["Required"] == true) {
                    $('[name="HomeAddress2Label"]').addClass("required");
                    $('[name="HomeAddress2Text"]').rules("add", {
                        required: true,
                        messages: {
                            required: "Required"
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $('[name="HomeAddress2Label"]').removeClass("required"); 
                }
                break;
           }
      }
```

[image]

Above image 1st I have selected `Gayana` country for this country `Address line2` is required and got error message. that correct then I have change to `USA` and I have removed rule for `Address Line2` but still message shows. How to removed all message after change my dropdown and see when submit again?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of removing the `required` class, use the [$.rules('remove',...)](http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/#rules(-%E2%80%9Cremove%E2%80%9D-rules-)) function:

```
$('[name="HomeAddress1Label"]').rules('remove',{
    required:true
});
```

You may need to re-validate after this change as well -

```
$('form').valid();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks dirty but below solution worked for me.

```
$("#Name").rules("remove", "required"); //Only this line did not worked in my case
$("#Name").removeClass("input-validation-error");
$("#Name").next().removeClass("field-validation-error");
$("#Name").next().addClass("field-validation-valid");
$("#Name").next().children().text("");
```